# Shell: how to create a list variable from several args

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have shell script that runs a cli command with 3 or more args, i can't specify in advance the number of args that will be passed to the script.

```
cmd=$(aws emr add-steps --cluster-id ${1} --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR, Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar, Name="$2",Args=[$3,$4,....])
```

i tried to replace `Args=[$3,$4,....]` by `Args=[${@:3}]` but the arguments are not comma-separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of `IFS` inside the command substitution and use `$*` instead of `$@`:

```
cmd=$(IFS=,;
      aws emr add-steps --cluster-id ${$1} \
         --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR, \
         Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar, \
         Name="$2",Args=["${*:3}"])
```

The semicolon after `IFS=,` is optional as long as the call to `aws` begins on the next line, not immediately after the assignment.

`${$1}` is an syntax error, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Args=$(printf "%s," "${@:3}")
```

to print all argument from 3rd argument onwards all ending with a comma. (There will be a trailing comma)

If you want to avoid trailing comma then use a variable to store `printf` output and trim ending `,` as this code:

```
printf -v args "%s," "${@:3}"
Args="${args%,}"
```

Comment: when add `echo $Args` i get an empty output.

Comment: It should be `echo "$args"` (all lowercase) btw this requires `bash`

Comment: same thing, `bash test.sh "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" ` but the output still empty.